# Errors in building caffe on Jetson-TK1 board

Tags: cuda, deep-learning, caffe

I am building caffe on my Jetson-TK1 board. The board runs Ubuntu Linux 32bit. My Makefile.config is as follow

```
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
#USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
#CPU_ONLY := 1

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
#CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda-6.5
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := atlas
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
BLAS_INCLUDE := /usr/include
BLAS_LIB := /usr/lib

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
# MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.

PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
# ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
# PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib

# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
# WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/local/hdf5/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/local/hdf5/lib


# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib


# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
# USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

I can do `make all` with success.
The errors came when I run `make test`.
The errors are

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/opt/caffee$ make test
CXX/LD -o .build_debug/test/test_all.testbin src/caffe/test/test_caffe_main.cpp
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<float>::forward_gpu_bias(float*, float const*)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<double>::backward_gpu_gemm(double const*, double const*, double*)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<double>::backward_gpu_bias(double*, double const*)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<float>::forward_gpu_gemm(float const*, float const*, float*, bool)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<float>::backward_gpu_bias(float*, float const*)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<double>::weight_gpu_gemm(double const*, double const*, double*)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::curandGetErrorString(curandStatus)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<double>::forward_gpu_bias(double*, double const*)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<float>::backward_gpu_gemm(float const*, float const*, float*)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::cublasGetErrorString(cublasStatus_t)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<double>::forward_gpu_gemm(double const*, double const*, double*, bool)'
.build_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BaseConvolutionLayer<float>::weight_gpu_gemm(float const*, float const*, float*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_debug/test/test_all.testbin] Error 1
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/opt/caffee$
```

I use CUDA-6.5.

What could be wrong with this build?

**EDIT 1:**
The [link](http://petewarden.com/2014/10/25/how-to-run-the-caffe-deep-learning-vision-library-on-nvidias-jetson-mobile-gpu-board/) what  @Klaus Prinoth mentioned is useful. Now I can build. I can also test `build/tools/caffe time --model=models/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt --gpu=0` for both CPU and GPU. But when I do `make -j 8 runtest`, I got the message as `Check Failed`. I am not sure what is wrong. The message is

```
[----------] 5 tests from DBTest/1, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLMDB
[ RUN      ] DBTest/1.TestNext
[       OK ] DBTest/1.TestNext (63 ms)
[ RUN      ] DBTest/1.TestSeekToFirst
[       OK ] DBTest/1.TestSeekToFirst (119 ms)
[ RUN      ] DBTest/1.TestKeyValue
[       OK ] DBTest/1.TestKeyValue (118 ms)
[ RUN      ] DBTest/1.TestWrite
F0807 23:14:56.323696 19992 db.hpp:109] Check failed: mdb_status == 0 (-30792 vs. 0) MDB_MAP_FULL: Environment mapsize limit reached
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @ 0x4330f060  (unknown)
    @ 0x4330ef5c  (unknown)
    @ 0x4330eb78  (unknown)
    @ 0x43310f98  (unknown)
    @ 0x43cc2386  caffe::db::LMDBTransaction::Put()
    @   0x155a36  caffe::DBTest_TestWrite_Test<>::TestBody()
    @   0x248d00  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @   0x242124  testing::Test::Run()
    @   0x2421b6  testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @   0x24228a  testing::TestCase::Run()
    @   0x242438  testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @   0x248a88  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @   0x241c26  testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @    0x81314  main
    @ 0x43f5f632  (unknown)
make: *** [runtest] Aborted
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/opt/caffe$
```

What does the message mean?

Comment: where did you download this caffe?

Comment: From this link <http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html>. There is GitHub

Comment: Try [this tutorial](http://petewarden.com/2014/10/25/how-to-run-the-caffe-deep-learning-vision-library-on-nvidias-jetson-mobile-gpu-board/), this is with a caffe properly for TK1 from a guy on github who fixed some errors.

Comment: Thanks. good link. Will try and update.

Comment: [This one](http://planspace.org/20150614-the_nvidia_jetson_tk1_with_caffe_on_mnist/) is about the same thing, but there are a few differences in downloading the package, so if the other doesn't work you could give it a try.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth, thanks it worked. I can build. I got a check failed message for the make -j 8 runtest. What does the message mean? I put as EDIT 1: in the original post.

Comment: I found the discussion here https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1861. The second link has also has the same solution for check failed problem. The problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: @batuman: Please summarise the steps you took to solve the problem and add them as a short answer to this question (it is perfectly OK to do that), and you will be able to accept it later). This will get the question off the unanswered list and leave something for the next person with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problems following the steps below. These are the steps mentioned in this [link](http://planspace.org/20150614-the_nvidia_jetson_tk1_with_caffe_on_mnist/).

(1)Need to make sure all the dependencies are installed. They are

```
    sudo apt-get install \
    libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler gfortran \
    libboost-dev cmake libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev \
    libboost-thread-dev libboost-system-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libgflags-dev \
    libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev gcc-4.7 g++-4.7
```

Since I don't use Python, I skip steps necessary for Python interfaces.

(2)Get the caffe sources

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
cd caffe
cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
```

(3) Need to change 1099511627776 to 536870912 in src/caffe/util/db.cpp before `make -j 8 runtest`, without that it will lead to `MDB_MAP_FULL error in runtest`.
My Makefile.config is shown in the original post.
Then you are ready for

```
make -j 8 all
make -j 8 test
make -j 8 runtest
```

Performance differences on CPU and GPU processing can be tested with

For GPU: "`run build/tools/caffe time --model=models/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt --gpu=0`"

For CPU: "`run build/tools/caffe time --model=models/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt`"
Thanks to @Klaus Prinoth, for giving me the link.